# Contour plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, contour, r-plotly

I'm trying to create a contour plot in R from 3 vectors.

I have:

```
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y=c(0,10,20,0,10,20,0,10,20)
z=c(900,800,700,600,500,400,300,200,100)
```

And I want to plot something like that (made in SigmaPlot)
[image]

How can I do it in R?

Comment: Have you tried to write code for this? If so, you should post it, and show where you are stuck. The package `ggplot2` and `geom_contour()` would be a starting point: e.g., `ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + geom_contour()` From there, you would change the fill, add a legend and labeling.

Comment: Or you could look at the base graphics function `contour`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `plotly` package:

```
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y=c(0,10,20,0,10,20,0,10,20)
z=c(900,800,700,600,500,400,300,200,100)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)

library(plotly)    
p <- plot_ly(data = df, x=~x,y=~y, z=~z, type = "contour", colorscale='Jet')
```

This will give you:

```
> p
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using "pallete" for better shade of colors.